# How to use thousand line separator in edit text in android........?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to separate automatically edit text like (9,99,999) like this. I searched for this on the web but I have not found a proper solution for this.

## MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcherForThousand(editText));    NumberTextWatcherForThousand.trimCommaOfString(editText.getText().toString());
}
}
```

## NumberTextWatcherForThousand

```
    public class NumberTextWatcherForThousand implements TextWatcher {
    EditText editText;
    public NumberTextWatcherForThousand(EditText editText) {
        this.editText = editText;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        try
        {
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            String value = editText.getText().toString();


            if (value != null && !value.equals(""))
            {

                if(value.startsWith(".")){
                    editText.setText("0.");
                }
                if(value.startsWith("0") && !value.startsWith("0.")){
                    editText.setText("");

                }


                String str = editText.getText().toString().replaceAll(",", "");
                if (!value.equals(""))
                    editText.setText(getDecimalFormattedString(str));
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
            }
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }

    }

    public static String getDecimalFormattedString(String value)
    {
        StringTokenizer lst = new StringTokenizer(value, ".");
        String str1 = value;
        String str2 = "";
        if (lst.countTokens() > 1)
        {
            str1 = lst.nextToken();
            str2 = lst.nextToken();
        }
        String str3 = "";
        int i = 0;
        int j = -1 + str1.length();
        if (str1.charAt( -1 + str1.length()) == '.')
        {
            j--;
            str3 = ".";
        }
        for (int k = j;; k--)
        {
            if (k < 0)
            {
                if (str2.length() > 0)
                    str3 = str3 + "." + str2;
                return str3;
            }
            if (i == 3)
            {
                str3 = "," + str3;
                i = 0;
            }
            str3 = str1.charAt(k) + str3;
            i++;
        }

    }

    public static String trimCommaOfString(String string) {
        if(string.contains(",")){
            return string.replace(",","");}
        else {
            return string;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Oracle provides some options for number formatting. You might wanna check something similar in android. One of the link I found         http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 1):

This will format the text and add commas in thousands place inside your edit text.

```
@Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                try {
                    // The comma in the format specifier does the trick
                   editText.setText(String.format("%,d", Long.parseLong(editable.toString())));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this below code :-

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private DecimalFormat df;
    private DecimalFormat dfnd;
    private boolean hasFractionalPart;

    private EditText et;

    public NumberTextWatcher(EditText et)
    {
        df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
        df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
        dfnd = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
        this.et = et;
        hasFractionalPart = false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = "NumberTextWatcher";

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        et.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        try {
            int inilen, endlen;
            inilen = et.getText().length();

            String v = s.toString().replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "");
            Number n = df.parse(v);
            int cp = et.getSelectionStart();
            if (hasFractionalPart) {
                et.setText(df.format(n));
            } else {
                et.setText(dfnd.format(n));
            }
            endlen = et.getText().length();
            int sel = (cp + (endlen - inilen));
            if (sel > 0 && sel <= et.getText().length()) {
                et.setSelection(sel);
            } else {
                // place cursor at the end?
                et.setSelection(et.getText().length() - 1);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            // do nothing?
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // do nothing?
        }

        et.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        if (s.toString().contains(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator())))
        {
            hasFractionalPart = true;
        } else {
            hasFractionalPart = false;
        }
    }

}
```

and in your edittext

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcher(editText));
```

Answer (score 0):

**In build.gradle add following lines**

```
repositories{
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.BlacKCaT27:CurrencyEditText:v1.4.4'
```

}

**Instead of EditText use following Code**

```
<com.blackcat.currencyedittext.CurrencyEditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

check this link https://github.com/BlacKCaT27/CurrencyEditText